# not working the change of bower's default components folder

Tags: bower, bower-install

I have tired to change bower default folder. I have created two files

**1.** .bowerrc.json
**2.** bower.json

The content of `.bowerrc.json` file

```
{
  "directory": "Vendors"
}
```

and the content of bower.json file

```
{
  "name": "Sardar",
  "description": "Human Resource Management System",
  "main": "index.html",
  "moduleType": [],
  "keywords": [
    "AngularJS"
  ],
  "authors": [
    "Md. Shohel Rana"
  ],
  "license": "Restrict",
  "homepage": "",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

**Both are same root**. when I run the command `bower install` that installs everything in a folder named bower_components. but need install into Vendors folder that is not working. Thanks for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

just remove .json extension from the file .bowerrc.json
and again run `bower install`